# Handling key structure in DynamoDB backed API pagination

Tags: api, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I've been looking at how I would implement pagination in a API backed by DynamoDB. Dynamo's approach to pagination is straightforward enough and well [documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Pagination). The wrinkle I find in designing a query string is the LastEvaluatedKey being an object (i.e. the hash, range and index info as needed) rather than a string value.

Is there any experience or advice about how to implement API pagination using DynamoDB, given the structured key?

Comment: can you elaborate on structured key? if you know the table primary key structure you should be able to figure out how to translate that from a string sent to your api

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. Tables can have different key schemas so the structure may (and does in the case I have in mind) vary by table. That's one of the reasons I don't want to expose it. Here's a made up example, though; for table with a hash key 'id' and a global secondary index with hash key 'bucket' and range key 'timestamp', then the key structure is { id: '...', bucket: '...', timestamp: '...' }.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have control over the API implementation, so I'd keep a translation map

```
API <endpoint, key*> ---> DynamoDB key structure object
```

so that whenever i get a request to one of my API endpoints I can translate it on the fly to the correct DynamoDB key and do a generalized DynamoDB [query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html).

This should help you translate key* into a LastEvaluatedKey

Answer (score 0):

I could serialize and encode the key structure to produce a single opaque pagination token that can then be used in API calls, eg. as a query string parameter.

I could also encrypt the token if I wanted it to be harder for clients to determine the key structure.